# Woocommerce - Remove the available product inventory number from the shop page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

On the shop page that displays all the products in my e-commerce store, it's currently displaying the product count (inventory) number beside the name of the product as so:

[image]

I found and tried to use this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', 'woo_remove_category_products_count' );
function woo_remove_category_products_count() {
return;
}
```

But it doesn't work because it removes the 'only 5 left in stock' notice on the individual product page and thats not what I need.

Then I have tried to use CSS:

```css
.count {
    display: none !important;
}
```

But doesn't work either.

I really hope someone has a solution for this. All suggestions very welcome and thanks for your efforts in advance!

Comment: I know, it's very weird. I also have tried inspecting the element and it doesn't have tag. Here's the site when you can see the inventory of 10 next to the title of each product http://www.devo.co.uk/product-category/kaycee/

Comment: You have been absolutely amazing! I figured out the issue. I have some code in my functions.php file to show the 'out of stock' tag on the all products shop page instead of just the single product page and that was causing the issue. Well I've removed it now but it's not exactly what I want. But you've been amazing with you're suggestions. Thank you so much. If you're at all interested, I've isolated the real issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381969/how-can-i-display-the-out-of-stock-tag-on-the-shop-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@*Update1:***

---

Try this snippet code function *(without guaranty, because untested)*, but logically it should do the job *(see the extract of the template below)*:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
```

Or alternatively:

```
add_action('init', function(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
}
```

---

First find the function involved in that count: **`woocommerce_result_count()`**.

Then I have Find the related hook:

Here is the extract of the template **`archive-product.php`** that shows the hook:

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20       <==== ==== ==== ==== Here @@@ !
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
?>
```

---

**@*update2:*** — This is working too *(see update3: the alternative)*

---

Last try based on [**this old thread *(see at the end)***](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-the-product-count-on-woocommerce-categories), overriding the native function on shop page:

```
add_action('init', function(){
    if(is_shop()){
        function woocommerce_result_count(){
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
if(is_shop()){
    function woocommerce_result_count(){
        return;
    }
}
```

---

**@*update3:*** -- The other working solution *(overriding template file)*

---

The function [**`woocommerce_result_count()`**](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_result_count.html#745) refer to **`loop/result-count.php`** WooCommerce template, as you can see in this source extract:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_result_count' ) ) {

    /**
     * Output the result count text (Showing x - x of x results).
     *
     * @subpackage  Loop
     */
    function woocommerce_result_count() {
        wc_get_template( 'loop/result-count.php' );
    }
}
```

## The solution:

is in:  **`loop/result-count.php`** WooCommerce template, adding: **`|| is_shop()`** to the **`if`** statement *(on line 27)*, this way:

```
<?php
/**
 * Result Count
 *
 ... / ...

 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $wp_query;

// @@@ Here we avoid count on shop page <==== ==== ==== ==== ADDING " || is_shop() "…
if ( ! woocommerce_products_will_display() || is_shop() )
    return;
/*
 ... / ...

 */
```

That works this time…

Reference: [Overriding Templates via a Theme (+Template Structure)](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so log into wordpress and go to WooCommerce > Settings > Inventory (tab)

Then set Stock display format to never display stock information.

Comment: As mentioned above, this doesn't work. Thank you for your suggestion